# Activating a profile when files exists using wildcards

Tags: maven, cucumber, activation, profiles

I activate in a parent `pom.xml` Spring support using

```
<activation>
    <file>
        <exists>src/main/resources/*beans.xml</exists>
    </file>
</activation>
```

This works fine.

When I try to activate the CucumberJVM stuff in a profile using

```
<activation>
    <file>
        <exists>src/test/resources/**/*.feature</exists>
    </file>
</activation>
```

However this refuses to work. So I guess the `**` wildcard is ignored in this context.

Is this normal, is there a workaround to get this profile activated when `.feature` files are present?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm actually surprised  that `*beans.xml` works.

As far as I can see, **wildcards are not supported** in file activation. The source code that calculates profile activation based on `<file>` can be found in [FileProfileActivator](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/xref/org/apache/maven/model/profile/activation/FileProfileActivator.html). The core logic goes like this:

```
String path = //<file><exists> ...

RegexBasedInterpolator interpolator = new RegexBasedInterpolator();
interpolator.addValueSource(/* ${basedir} suppert */)
interpolator.addValueSource( new MapBasedValueSource( context.getProjectProperties() ) );
interpolator.addValueSource( new MapBasedValueSource( context.getUserProperties() ) );
interpolator.addValueSource( new MapBasedValueSource( context.getSystemProperties() ) );
path = interpolator.interpolate( path, "" );
path = pathTranslator.alignToBaseDirectory( path, basedir );
File f = new File( path );
if ( !f.isAbsolute() ){
    return false;
}
boolean isActive = f.exists();
```

And neither `interpolate(...)` nor `alignToBaseDirectory(...)` process wildcards.

As a workaround you can try some gimick with `<activation><property>`, but that would require calling the maven build with a shell script.

Comment: Note that in 3.0.5 source code (https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/xref/org/apache/maven/model/profile/activation/FileProfileActivator.html), `context.getProjectProperties()` is never called.

Answer (score 4):

In our project, we use the configuration below to package all tests as jar-files using the jar-plugin:

```
    <activation>
        <file>
            <exists>src/test/resources/com/companyname/platform/test/</exists>
        </file>
    </activation>
```

This is able to work because:

- we create boilerplate code using archetypes
- most people only put resource files in the root folder
- the profile activation works on directories, at least in Maven 3.0.5